# Why do Proton rockets use two types of main engines in its second stage?

Tags: launch, spacecraft, engines, stages, proton-m

The second stage of Proton (8K-82K) rocket has two types of main engines (RD-0210 and RD-0211). Does someone knows why?

[image: Proton rockets - the first version, 1965, and the recent M version.]

Answer (score 8):

They are the same basic engine, just the RD-0211 has a heat exchanger, that is lacking on the RD-0210.

The long history of the Proton went through three or more major revisions, and the engines were renumbered in each revision, as a pair.  Each time, one with heat exchanger, one without.

There is much more detail on Wikipedia about the [RD-210 Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-0210).

Comment: The heat exchanger is used to pressurize the propellant tanks; presumably only one is needed, so leaving it off 3 of the 4 engines is weight-saving?

Comment: At least on SSME the heat exchanger was a scary thing; best to leave it off if you can.

Comment: what makes me wonder is why just one engine has a heat exchanger. I would expect 2 engines.

Comment: @JuniorMiranda: This design decision suggests the proton upper stage can't tolerate an engine out anyway.